# Generator for `model.fit()` Input rather than Collection? (training data too large for memory)

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, memory, tflearn

tf-learn models' fit function can be passed training and test data like so:

```
model = tflearn.DNN(nn)

model.fit({'input': X_train},
          {'targets': Y_train},
          n_epoch=10,
          validation_set=(
              {'input': X_test},
              {'targets': Y_test}
          ))
```

where `nn` is the definition of a model. However, what if the collections such as `X_train` are too large for memory?

In my case I have compressed sparse binary vectors (cells either being 1 or 0) in the form of a list of indices and an integer coding for the number of dimensions of the vector, which allow me to reconstruct the original vectors.

That collections of compressed vectors do fit into memory, not the collections containing the full vectors though. Therefore I tried to instead pass a generator over `X_train` and the other collections (now containing the compressed vectors) that reconstructs the full vectors on the fly, but `model.fit` required a `len()` function. So I defined a custom feeder class like so:

```
class Feeder:
    def __init__(self, data, convert):
        self.data = data
        self.convert = convert

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        for item in self.data:
            yield self.convert(item)
```

which I call like this:

```
def reconstruct_vector(non_zero_indices, dimensionality):
    """
    returns a vector of zeros and ones reconstructed from a sparse vector
    and a dimensions value
    """
    vec = np.zeros(dimensionality)
    for i in non_zero_intraining data too large for memorydices:
        vec[i] = 1
    return vec

item_to_input_vector = lambda item : reconstruct_vector(item[0], item[1])
item_to_target_vector = lambda item : np.array([1,0]) if item else np.array([0,1])

model.fit({'input': Feeder(X_train, item_to_input_vector)},
          {'targets': Feeder(Y_train, item_to_target_vector)},
          n_epoch=10,
          validation_set=(
              {'input': Feeder(X_test, item_to_input_vector)},
              {'targets': Feeder(Y_test, item_to_target_vector)}
          ))
```

But that also does not work, as I get some cryptic error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 187, in fill_feed_dict_queue
    data = self.retrieve_data(batch_ids)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/data_flow.py", line 222, in retrieve_data
    utils.slice_array(self.feed_dict[key], batch_ids)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflearn/utils.py", line 187, in slice_array
    return X[start]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

So, what would be the correct way to go about this?